# Specific external monitor no longer detected

Tags: multiple-monitors

I have a Dell XPS 13 with Ubuntu 16.04. First time I've connected an external monitor (1080p TV) it works just fine. But some day Ubuntu stop detecting it.

If I boot the system from USB with a fresh Ubuntu 16.04 the monitor is detected correctly. It seems that some information in the system is preventing this monitor to be detected.

How can I reset the external display configuration to solve this? My system has Intel display controller.

This is the output of xrandr with the monitor connected (but not detected):
$ xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 32767 x 32767
eDP1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 294mm x 165mm
   1920x1080     59.93*+  59.93
   1680x1050     59.95    59.88
   1600x1024     60.17
   1400x1050     59.98
   1600x900      60.00
   1280x1024     60.02
   1440x900      59.89
   1280x960      60.00
   1368x768      60.00
   1360x768      59.80    59.96
   1152x864      60.00
   1280x720      60.00
   1024x768      60.00
   1024x576      60.00
   960x540       60.00
   800x600       60.32    56.25
   864x486       60.00
   640x480       59.94
   720x405       60.00
   640x360       60.00
DP1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
VIRTUAL1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)

When working, DP1 is the one used by the system.

Thanks a lot,
D.

Comment: Have you tried forcing output through DP1, like in this answer? https://askubuntu.com/a/968522/574724