# I have two monitors with two different dpi settings, how do I change so they look nice and crisp?

Tags: display-resolution, xrandr, external-monitor, hdpi

Okay, so I have a 15 inch 4k laptop (3840*2160) that is my main display. I then have a 20 inch monitor (1600*1900) sit on the left side of my laptop. What would I type in the terminal to make the screens looks nice and scaled correctly.

Also please note, that I want the display to go back to its normal self when I unplug it.

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you running?

Comment: I am using version: 16.04

Comment: Please see if this answer can help you https://askubuntu.com/a/968522/574724

Comment: I tried it, it did not help me much...